# Google foobar gearing_up_for_destruction for fraction points

Tags: python, algorithm

I came up with this problem from Google's coding problems, and tried to solve it, but got stuck for some specific cases.

```
Challenge

As Commander Lambda's personal assistant, you've been assigned the task of configuring the LAMBCHOP doomsday device's axial orientation gears. It should be pretty simple - just add gears to create the appropriate rotation ratio. But the problem is, due to the layout of the LAMBCHOP and the complicated system of beams and pipes supporting it, the pegs that will support the gears are fixed in place.

The LAMBCHOP's engineers have given you lists identifying the placement of groups of pegs along various support beams. You need to place a gear on each peg (otherwise the gears will collide with unoccupied pegs). The engineers have plenty of gears in all different sizes stocked up, so you can choose gears of any size, from a radius of 1 on up. Your goal is to build a system where the last gear rotates at twice the rate (in revolutions per minute, or rpm) of the first gear, no matter the direction. Each gear (except the last) touches and turns the gear on the next peg to the right.

Given a list of distinct positive integers named pegs representing the location of each peg along the support beam, write a function answer(pegs) which, if there is a solution, returns a list of two positive integers a and b representing the numerator and denominator of the first gear's radius in its simplest form in order to achieve the goal above, such that radius = a/b. The ratio a/b should be greater than or equal to 1. Not all support configurations will necessarily be capable of creating the proper rotation ratio, so if the task is impossible, the function answer(pegs) should return the list [-1, -1].

For example, if the pegs are placed at [4, 30, 50], then the first gear could have a radius of 12, the second gear could have a radius of 14, and the last one a radius of 6. Thus, the last gear would rotate twice as fast as the first one. In this case, pegs would be [4, 30, 50] and answer(pegs) should return [12, 1].

The list pegs will be given sorted in ascending order and will contain at least 2 and no more than 20 distinct positive integers, all between 1 and 10000 inclusive.
```

Here's my solution

```py
def get_last_radius(pegs, radius):
  for i in range(1, len(pegs)):
    pegs_range = pegs[i] - pegs[i - 1]
    radius = pegs_range - radius

  return radius

def get_first_radius(pegs):
  first_range = pegs[1] - pegs[0]
  for first_radius in range(2, first_range, 2):
    last_radius = get_last_radius(pegs, first_radius)
    if first_radius == last_radius * 2:
      return [first_radius, 1]
  return [-1, -1]
```

I assume that there can not be any floating points, that's why I'm returning 1 as the denominator for all the cases. But searching a little bit, I found this post

[Google foobar gearing_up_for_destruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465866/google-foobar-gearing-up-for-destruction)

which kind of tells that there are cases with floating points, but I still can't find it.

If first radius is `*.x` for example, the other one should be `*.y` where `x + y = 1`. So for the third gear, it should again be `*.x` as the pegs are placed only at *INTEGER* locations. Can someone show a specific test case with floating numbers please?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not meet the requirements (which I didn't at first too). 
Here's what you may have missed:
1. `The engineers have plenty of gears in all different sizes stocked up, so you can choose gears of any size, from a radius of 1 on up.`
That means, when you find the first gear radius, you have to loop back again to see if *any* gear has radius < 1.
2. `return [first_radius, 1]`
The radius will not always be an integer. It is clearly stated that `returns a list of two positive integers a and b representing the numerator and denominator of the first gear's radius in its simplest form in order to achieve the goal above, such that radius = a/b`. And here is the test case where the return radius is not integer: `[25,105,145,170]`, which returns `[130, 3]`.
In order to solve this, you need math. Try to find the *last* gear radius with n = 2, 3, 4, 5... (input list's length), and you will see the pattern. Good luck.